# Prove that the condition $x(\tau)>\xi$ of a divergent integral implies that $x(t)>\xi$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Let $ E, J \subset \mathbb R$ be open intervals and let functions $h:J \to \mathbb R$ and $g: E \to \mathbb R$ be continuous.  let $\xi \in E$ and assume that $g(\xi)=0$.  Define $f:J \times E \to \mathbb R$ by setting $f(t,z)=h(t)g(z)$ and consider the differential equation $\dot x(t) = f(t,x(t))=h(t)g(x(t)))$.  Let $x: I \to E$ be a solution.

I have some assumptions:

(1) $g(z)\neq 0$ for all $z \in [\xi, \xi +\delta]$ where $\delta > 0$ and that the improper interal $\int_ \xi^{\xi + \delta} \frac{dz}{g(z)} $ is divergent

(2) There exists $\tau \in I$ such that $x(\tau)>\xi$.

How can I show that $x(t) >\xi$ for all $t \in I$??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess $I$ means $J$?

Comment: @Kundor This is how I found it written but I suggest you are right.

Comment: @Kundor do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some thoughts (I don't really know about these kinds of differential equations, however.)

Suppose that there is some $t$ such that $x(t) \leq \xi$; then, since $x$ is continuous on $J$, there is a $c \in J$ such that $x(c) = \xi$.
More specifically, if we assume (without loss of generality) that $\delta \leq x(\tau)$, the interval $(\xi, \xi+\delta)$ has a nonempty open preimage
under $x$; let $(c,d)$ be one of the disjoint open intervals making up this preimage such that $x(c) = \xi$ and $x(d) = \xi + \delta$
(or vice versa, in which case modify the following accordingly).

Then for $t$ in the interval $(c,d)$, $g(x(t)) \neq 0$, so $h(t) = \dfrac{\dot{x}(t)}{g(x(t))}$.

So
$$
\int_c^d h(t) dt =
\int_c^d \frac {\dot{x}(t)}{g(x(t))} dt =
\int_{\xi}^{\xi+\delta} \frac{1}{g(u)} du
$$
where we have used substitution with $u = x(t)$.
This is a divergent integral,
which is a contradiction,
since $h$ is continuous on $[c,d]$ and thus integrable.